How does "kubectl top node" calculates the usage percentage?
I'm trying to get programmatically something similar to kubectl top node. I can get each node CPU/memory usage info and I also want to print the %, but I don't know where can I find information about the total to compare against.
Example:
NAME           CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
master-6zjs4   708m         14%    4677Mi          64%       
master-rjvg6   942m         18%    5177Mi          71%       
master-w6hpc   1415m        28%    5745Mi          78%       
worker-277g5   970m         3%     12441Mi         5%        
worker-4hf4x   902m         3%     16310Mi         6%        
worker-5jcz7   802m         3%     10173Mi         4%        
worker-5s74n   774m         3%     9075Mi          3%        
worker-6dckk   699m         2%     7392Mi          3%        
worker-kv9lh   713m         2%     11621Mi         4%        
worker-whk6x   991m         3%     10775Mi         4%

For the last node in the list I get this usage info:
"usage": {
  "cpu": "990697725n",
  "memory": "11033864Ki"
}

My question is: which field/attribute/property stores the total limit of CPU in order to calculate that 3% that is shown in the command output?
I think the API library is not important. In any case I'm using Java fabric8 kubernetes-client.

how to get the Node CPU% and MEMORY% value using java io.fabric8 kubernetes-client library seems to have a complete answer to this.  The denominator is the status.allocatable property of the Node object, which according to that question needs to be separately fetched.

Thank you very much, David. That post is exactly what I was looking for and I didn't see it. I apologize.
